# changing content-type with enctype in form

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

I do not understand enough problems with http headers, I am trying upload file but now this is so far from me, and I need explanation why I get `content-type` `application/json` if I add `enctype="multipart/form-data` in form? Because I think for this reaseon `req.file` is undefined

html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="sendProductForm" ng-submit="product.sendProduct(productData, sendProductForm.$valid)" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 form-horizontal adding-form" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">       
      <input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

api

```
router.post('/courses', multer({ dest:'./uploads/' }).single('file'), function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.file)
  console.log(req.headers)
})
```

service

```
userFactory.createNewCourse = function(productData){
  return $http.post('/api/courses', productData)
}
```

controller function

```
app.sendProduct = function(productData) {        
    User.createNewCourse(app.productData).then(function(data){
      console.log(data)
    })  
}
```

extract from `req.headers`

```
  'content-length': '156',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
```

Comment: As a user, are you uploading a JSON document? `req.headers` is the request from the browser to the server. Try using the Network inspector in your browser to see what the request body is. Do you recognize it?

Comment: I think I recognize it, thanks for tip. My point is uploading file pdf or image document